# Interpolation of word by scholars Update Question

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, academic-latin

In my [previous question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18615/interpolation-of-words-by-scholars-leads-to-changes-in-the-meaning), I ask why "non" was added by scholars. Reading more I found this from a [1543 Latin book](https://gutenberg.beic.it/view/action/nmets.do?DOCCHOICE=12903859.xml&dvs=1660660178502%7E216&locale=en_US&search_terms=&show_metadata=true&adjacency=&VIEWER_URL=/view/action/nmets.do?&DELIVERY_RULE_ID=7&divType=)
[image]
In [19's book](https://archive.org/details/vitruviidearchit00vitr/page/208/mode/2up) (reconstructed one) on "non" the note is

> non add. Joc(ant habere)
> [image]

In [this book](https://archive.org/details/bub_gb_JCZGdU607WAC/page/n237/mode/2up), it's clear
[image]

What does the note say? What is meant by the "Joc" abbreviation? Was the 15-century book written in the right way?

Comment: For some reason, the Gutenberg link isn't working for me.

Comment: @cmw wiki provides the  link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitruvius#:~:text=Strasbourg%3A%20Georg%20Messerschmidt
page 216

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joc. is an earlier edition of the text by Giovanni Giocondo. Look on p. xii of the book to see the other editions and on the previous pages for the manuscripts Rose used in compiling his text.

The note says that Joc. added *non*, but did so before *habere*; as in, the editor realized it needed *non* (probably fell out as I mentioned in the other thread), but Rose disagrees with its placement.

Comment: A quibble: it's actually a printed edition, not a manuscript (= Giovanni Giocondo's Florence edition).

Comment: @cnread Thanks. I was too hasty. Should be accurate now.