# How grammatical mistake transmitted in manuscripts

Tags: classical-latin, academic-latin

In my [previse](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/18668/10551) posts, I asked the question on interpolation of the word "non" in sentences, community from both Reddit and stack provide a very detailed and good answer, but while reading all the answers, one thing come to my mind, why and how this error get transmitted in all manuscript,(except one) because, this error was a grammatical mistake if any person read this manuscript in the 10th century because the oldest manuscript is from 9th century and first-time error was corrected in 1510, will read it correctly and understand the manuscript. [Link To Reddit Anwer with exception manuscript](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin/comments/wpxdug/comment/ikjkv5w/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Answer (score 7):

Although it sounds paradoxical, a good scribe is one who *does not* correct mistakes.

Looking through the whole corpus of transmitted texts, among the commonest errors are:

1. Correcting a non-existent error. You see a word that you don’t think exists, and “correct” it to one you know. For example the MS says “vinolent” and you correct it to “violent”.
2. Seeing a real error and deciding to correct it - but making a wrong guess as to what the original text was.

With time it has been discovered that copying MSS accurately and correcting errors are two separate disciplines with two separate sets of skills.

Comment: Can you provide any book on this topic?